# Detect sound level in a certain frequency range in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder

I am working on my iOS app and I need to detect sound level from a certain frequency range. [Here is](http://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/) a good tutorial for detecting sound level, but how to do that in specific frequency range in iOS SDK?

Comment: have you found anything on this....? I am also working on this kind of app. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture audio from the microphone (`AVAudioEngine` is a good API for doing that), calculate its Fourier Transform (the `Accelerate` framework will do that with blazing speed) and examine the amplitude of the frequency bucket corresponding to your frequency. If it's large then you've got a match.

A possibly simpler and more efficient technique would be a [Goertzal filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) which is good at detecting a given frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact use case, I can imagine that similar code as what's used in a musical instrument tuner app would work. A quick search found [this guitar tuning app](https://github.com/catch-twenty-two/iOS-Guitar-Tuner) which uses fast Fourier transforms. 
Note that FFTs are implemented in the Accelerate framework, and in this app they appear to be imported from some other library.